# Typescript Interface get property type from genetic T by key of T's Child

Tags: typescript

```
export const Message = {
    key: 'chat-lists-contacts',
    name: 'Message Contact',
    description: 'A contact message card',
    children: [],
};

export interface Template {
    key: string;
    name?: string;
    description?: string;
    class?: string;
    children?: Array<ComponentRef>;
}

export interface TemplateRef<T extends Template> {
    key: T['key']; // Is it possible to enforce that this be 'chat-lists-contacts'  
    children: Array<ComponentRef>;
}
```

// For above, I use as.

```
templateRef(): TemplateRef<typeof Message> {
    return {
      key: 'd', // It doesn't validate this as invalid, should require `chat-lists-contacts`
      children: [
        {
          id: 'id,
          settings: {
            inputs: [
              {
                key: 'styles',
                value: ''
              }
            ]
          }
        },
      ]
    };
  }
```

Please see inline comments; I want to use the object `Message` somewhere else so I wouldn't have to redeclare it.,

Comment: Does it work if you alter the `key` property of your definition of `Message` to be defined like `key: 'chat-lists-contacts' as const,`?  (That is, add `as const`).  If so, I can write it up.  If not, what specifically is the problem?  Also it helps when code in a question constitutes a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), without typos or undeclared dependencies.

Comment: @jcalz thanks, yes it works if I use `'chat-lists-contacts' as const`, is it a good thing to want everyone to write `typeof Message` everytime someone wants to pass this. Would be good to find a way for it to just be  `TemplateRef<Message>`.

Comment: There's no type named `Message`, so you can't do that.  If you want to define `type Message = typeof Message` then after this you can write `TemplateRef<Message>`.  This seems like a separate question, though.